# How do I change the color of the DrawerArrowToggle (hamburger) in ActionBar in Android?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I would like to change the color of the hamburger icon in the action bar of an Android app to white.  It's currently gray by default.  I am using the Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar style and have set the drawerArrowStyle attribute, but it does not seem to affect the color.

```html
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/orderview_blue</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/orderview_blue</item>
        <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/AppDrawerCustom</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppDrawerCustom" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
        <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

[image: ActionBar with gray hamburger]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I was able to resolve this issue by updating to build with version 23 of the Android SDK.  I realized I was building with version 21 and the issue does not happen when building with version 23.

Answer (score 0):

Add 'colorControlNormal' into you custom style like this

```
<style name="AppDrawerCustom" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
       <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item> 
</style>
```

Comment: I tried adding "colorControlNormal" item as indicated but it didn't work.  I also tried adding that item to the main app theme style and that didn't affect it either.